# Mongodb не запускается сервис. (mongodb: unrecognized service)

Tags: debian, mongodb

Дистрибутив: **debian7**.

Пытаюсь запустить mongo командой `service mongod start`.
Появляется ошибка:

> mongodb: unrecognized service

наверно, я как-то неправильно собрал конфиг.

Сейчас я постоянно запускаю сервис командой `mongod --smallfiles`, однако, когда я закрываю терминал соединение обрывается.

Как можно добавить *монгу* в *сервисы*, чтобы она была постоянно включена?

---

```
$ dpkg -S $(which mongod)
mongodb-org-server: /usr/bin/mongod
```

Comment: не дописали название Мне кажется должно быть `service mongodb start` .Вообще что бы не промахиваться с названием команды вы можете во время набора жать `tab` и будет выдаваться список возможных вариантов   .

Comment: Пробовал использовать и  `service mongodb start` но ошибка та же

Comment: что возвращают команды `which mongod` и `dpkg -S $(which mongod)`?

Comment: `/usr/bin/mongod` и `mongodb-org-server: /usr/bin/mongod
` соответсвенно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

судя по названию пакета (*mongodb-org-server*), установлен он не из репозиториев дистрибутива, а из стороннего источника (вероятно, [отсюда](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/)).

если посмотреть внутрь пакета, то видно, что должен присутствовать скрипт `/etc/init.d/mongod`. предположительный вывод, основанный на содержимом файла `mongodb-org-server_3.2.3_amd64.deb`, полученного с вышеупомянутого веб-сервера:

```
$ dpkg -L mongodb-org-server | grep init.d
/etc/init.d/mongod
```

убедитесь, что входящий в пакет файл на самом деле присутствует и у него наличествует бит исполнимости.

если всё в порядке, то должны выполняться обычные команды *status*, *stop*, *start*:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mongod status
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mongod stop
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start
```

вот последней из этих команд и должен запускаться демон, а не прямым вызовом `sudo mongod ...`.

---

если вышеуказанные команды работают, а скрипт `/usr/sbin/service` по какой-то причине «не находит» скрипта `/etc/init.d/mongod`, то это явно совсем другой вопрос, который требует отдельного разбирательства.

---

если вышеуказанные команды работают, то, чтобы скрипт `/etc/init.d/mongod` выполнялся на указанных в нём же *runlevel-ах* (т.е., стартовал при загрузке и останавливался перед завершением работы), следует выполнить команду:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d mongod defaults
```

хотя, по идее, это излишне — все необходимые *символические ссылки* (*symlinks*) в каталогах `/etc/rc?.d/` должны были создаться автоматически при установке пакета (если этот сторонний пакет собран не совсем уж «криво»).